# Растянуть блок на всю высоту экрана

Tags: html, css, блок

Не могу понять, блок внутри `body` не растягивается на всю высоту экрана, пробовал `min-height`: `100%` / `100vh`

Результата нету, пожалуйста объясните почему это не срабатывает, и как можно растянуть?

Comment: Код в студию, того что вы делаете

Comment: Вы хотите на высоту экрана или на высоту соседнего контейнера растянуть?

Comment: На всю высоту страницы   https://codepen.io/anon/pen/werwvZ

Comment: А почему вы решили, что `.left-bar` не растягивается на всю высоту экрана? https://codepen.io/aliencash/pen/Ngarag?editors=1100

Comment: @AndreyFedorov http://imgur.com/a/sxlZc Нужно на всю высоту страницы

Comment: @AndreyFedorov а вот макет, http://imgur.com/a/iaCZs

Comment: @c0n а есть объективная причина почему вы flex не используете?

Comment: @AndreyFedorov было бы неплохо точнее вопрос формировать. Разница в растягивании по высоте экрана и высоте соседнего блока/страницы все же есть. Попробуйте подключить [EQCSS](http://elementqueries.com/). С ним без труда можно подогнать высоту левого блока по высоте правого. Можно так же скриптом простеньким взять высоту правого и если она превышает высоту левого, добавить стиль. Если не разберетесь, скину пример.

Comment: @AlexeyGiryayev Флекс боксы не особо хочу использовать ради одного блока, а можно как-то без особых спецификаций? Просто задать, без скрипта, без ничего

Comment: @AlexeyGiryayev Автору пишите, чего вы мне пишете? ) Впрочем я не согласен с тем, что вы предлагаете. Плодить зависимости когда ванильный css решает вопрос легко и непринужденно - это тяжкий горячечный бред. )))

Comment: @c0n Да что ж такое? Это я спрашивал про flex. ) Мой ответ на ваш комментарий, начните, и увидите как ваша верстальщицкая жизнь станет легче. Будете пихать его всюду. Обещаю. ))) А пока не начали, смотрите мой ответ ниже, это решение без флексов.

Comment: @AndreyFedorov да, перепутал немного пользователя. По поводу решений, тут у каждого свои предпочтения. Я бы делал через flexbox, а если человек не хочет, то небольшой скрипт подбирающий высоту, особо погоды не сделает.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Итак, если конструктивно ваш сайдбар более ничем не дополняется, а единственный элемент, который необходимо прижать к нижней части экрана - это лого, то вот вам наиболее простое решение. Рассмотрим все по порядку:

Первым делом, оборачиваем оба контейнера в какой-нить тег, так как они имеют `float: left`, от которого нам необходимо избавится из-за проблем с абсолютным позиционированием элементов. Для этого используем класс .clear, .clr и им подобные, в примере я просто задал следующие стили:

```
main:after {
 content: '';
 display: table;
 clear: both;
}
```

Далее, меняем цвета у body и блока с контентом, чтоб сайдбар не имел заднего фона. Выносим из него `.copyright`. Туда же добавляем абсолютную позицию и добавляем нижний отступ у `.left-bar` на высоту логотипа. Что-то вроде этого:

```
.left-bar {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-bottom: 110px;
}
.copyright {
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  bottom: 10px;
  width: 200px;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/1QBd5b5.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}
```

Почему мы вынесли его за пределы сайдбара? Для того, чтоб на мобильных устройствах мы могли потом переместить его в конец страницы (в примере я этого не делал, так как задача не стояла).

И сам результат:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
html {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #0e1416;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  height: 100%;
}
main {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #0e1416;
}
main:after {
  content: '';
 display: table;
 clear: both;
}
/* Left bar */
.left-bar {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-bottom: 110px;
}
.logotype {
  background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/Tbqbu8K.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  height: 100px;
}
.button-fl {
  width: 210px;
  height: 110px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-top: 7px;
}

.left-bar button {
  width: 165px;
  height: 35px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: #131b1e;
  border: none;
  color: #fff;
}
.left-bar button:hover {
  background-color: #2b99c5;
  transition: 1s;
}
.cats {
  margin-top: 10px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
}
.cats a {
  display: block;
  height: 35px;
  color: #5e7279;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.cats a:hover {
  color: #fff;
  transition: 0.5s ease;
}
.left-bar ul {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
  list-style-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/3p7hKZ7.png");
}
.left-bar ul > li {
  padding-left: 10px;
  list-style-type: none;
}
.left-bar ul > li:hover {
  list-style-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/eElkjFO.png");
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.active-cat-left {
  list-style-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/eElkjFO.png");
  color: #fff;
}
.active-cat-left a {
  color: #fff;
}
.copyright {
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  bottom: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  width: 200px;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/1QBd5b5.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}
/* ------------ */

.content-part {
  float: right;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #0b1012;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<html>

<head>
  <title>For example</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>
  <main>
    <div class="left-bar col-md-2">
      <a href="/">
        <div class="logotype"></div>
      </a>
      <div class="button-fl">
        <button class="sign-in">Войти</button>
        <button class="sign-up">Регистрация</button>
      </div>
      <div class="cats">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="/">Боевики</a></li>
          <li class="active-cat-left"><a href="/">Комедии</a></li>
          <li><a href="/">Фантастика</a></li>
          <li><a href="/">Драмы</a></li>
          <li><a href="/">Ужасы</a></li>
          <li class="active-cat-left"><a href="/">Приключения</a></li>
          <li><a href="/">Документальные</a></li>
          <li><a href="/">Семейные</a></li>
          <li class="active-cat-left"><a href="/">Военные</a></li>
          <li><a href="/">Криминал</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="content-part col-md-10">
      <div class="row no-gutter">text text text text text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text
        texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext
        text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text
        texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext
        text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text
        texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext
        text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text
        texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext
        text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text text text text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text
        texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext
        text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text
        texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext
        text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text
        texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext
        text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text
        texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext
        text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text text text text texttext text texttext text
        texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext
        text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text
        texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext
        text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text
        texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext
        text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text
        texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext
        text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text
        texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text text text text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext
        text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text
        texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext
        text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text
        texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext
        text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text
        texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext
        text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text
        texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text text text text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext
        text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text
        texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext
        text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text
        texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext
        text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text
        texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext
        text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text
        texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext
        text text text text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text
        texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext
        text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text
        texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext
        text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text
        texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext
        text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text
        texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext
        text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text text text text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text
        texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext
        text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text
        texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext
        text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text
        texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext
        text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text
        texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext
        text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text text text text texttext text texttext text
        texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext
        text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text
        texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext
        text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text
        texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext
        text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text
        texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext
        text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text
        texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text text text text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext
        text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text
        texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext
        text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text
        texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext
        text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text
        texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext
        text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text
        texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text text
      </div>
    </div>
    <a href="http://ensistudio.com" alt="Только лучшее качество!">
      <div class="copyright"></div>
    </a>
  </main>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, но я по прежнему не понимаю почему так происходит)

Comment: Что именно вам не понятно в данной подаче? Это тот результат, которого вы хотели добиться?

Comment: Результат тот, но почему оно не хотело растягиваться на 100%?

Comment: @c0n оно и не растягивается на всю высоту. Лого вынесен в угол с абсолютной позицией. А для сайдбара добавлен отступ внзу, чтоб он на этот лого не "наезжал", если высота контента будет не большой.

Answer (score 0):

```
html, body { width: 100%; height: 100%; }
```

Comment: Не работает, суть в том что сам контент страницы по высоте больше чем высота этого блока

Comment: пример кода можешь скинуть?

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/werwvZ

Comment: Апдейтнул кодпен

Comment: в body у тебя 2 блока div. Какой из них должен растягиваться на всю высоту?

Comment: Попробуй следующее:
1) Оберни два div внутри body в div с классом row (bootstrap`ий класс)
2) Убери у left-bar свойство display: inline
3) Убери у content-part свойство float

Comment: Левый бар (left-bar)

Comment: Инлайновское отображение там стоит для выравнивания по вертикали содержимого, а флоата на самом деле нету в шаблоне, просто на кодпене что-то не становился контент, в реал версии всё нормально

Comment: Так, а смысл в row обтягивать? Если строка растянется на всю ширину экрана, и контент часть съедет вниз, под лефт-бар

Answer (score 0):

100%  не правильно, нужно задавать min-height: 100vh но для корректной работе нужно в head

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Comment: В head уже стоит...

Comment: Пробывал 100vh, нету результата

Comment: Тогда нужен код.

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/werwvZ

Comment: И что не так ? О каком блоке речь идет?

Comment: Левый бар (left-bar)

Answer (score 0):

[Поправил ваш код](https://codepen.io/aliencash/pen/vZeygz?editors=1100). И все же не понятно почему вы не пользуетесь flex.

```
body {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}
.left-bar, .content-part {
  display: table-cell;
}
```

Comment: Надеюсь, что вы смотрели на результат своих стараний в Хроме.

Comment: Да, позорище. (

Comment: На самом деле, ваш вариант ему мог бы быть более удобным, задать сайдбару фикс.ширину и все корректно отобразится. Но, в этому случае вся верстка через Bootstrap не будет иметь смысла. Да, и табличные стили имеют массу недостатков. Но, как я уже писал выше, все зависит от конкретных задач и предпочтений верстальщика.